# Integrate GPS in JavafxPorts

Tags: javafx-8, javafxports, gluon

I have a Javafx application which is to be deployed in Android. My app needs to get the latitude and longitude but I dont know how to implement them. Can someone give me a code sample on how to do it in JavaFX?

**UPDATED:**

```
package com.gpstracker;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GPSTracker extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TextField t1 = new TextField();

        TextField t2 = new TextField();

        Button button = new Button("Show Location");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                PositionService positionService = PlatformFactory.getPlatform().getPositionService();
                Position position = positionService.getPosition();
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(20);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        root.getChildren().addAll(t1, t2, button);

        Rectangle2D visualBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, visualBounds.getWidth(), visualBounds.getHeight());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

**Gloun cant seem to find a class call PositionService and Position.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Gluon Mobile, the current position of a device can be tracked with the [PositionService](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/2.1.1/com/gluonhq/charm/down/common/PositionService.html). A sample code snippet:

```
PositionService positionService = PlatformFactory.getPlatform().getPositionService();
Position position = positionService.getPosition();
System.out.println("Current GPS position: " + position.getLatitude() + "," + position.getLongitude());
```

Comment: Sir, thank you for the answer, but Gluon cant seem to find the class PositionService and Position, please refer the updated question above.

Comment: Hi, why is it variable position is returning null? I already turned on my location in high accuracy. Any idea Sir?

Comment: When loading the PositionService the first time, it will try to set the current position to the last known position, by using the following method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String). This might return `null`. You can instead add a ChangeListener on the position property: `positionService.positionProperty().addListener((obs, oldPos, newPos) -> System.out.println("New GPS position: " + newPos.getLatitude() + "," + newPos.getLongitude()));`. This listener will be called each time the position changes.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved via the Gluon Mobile library.
http://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/

Answer (score 1):

To use `PositionService`, mentioned by [Joeri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4879050/joeri-sykora), you have to add a dependency to Gluon open source `charm-down` library. Here is a sample configuration for your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-common:2.0.0';
    desktopRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-desktop:2.0.0';
    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-android:2.0.0';
    iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-ios:2.0.0';
}
```

Comment: hi, where to place this code? Can you tell me where to place this codes in build.gradle?

Comment: your javafxports application should have build.gradle file in the root folder. This file may already have a dependency section, just add those 4 entries to it. 
You should also read javafxports documentation at http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_build_gradle